# Automate delete content of remote org mode file!

Tags: org-mode, remote

Linux Mint 19.3

Emacs 26.3

Dired+

I use Google drive. To connect I use rclone. As result I success connect to my google drive.

In dired mode I open to.do.org file in Google's drive

Edit file and save by C-x-s

[image]

The press C-x d. And as you can see the size of to.do.org is 0 bytes!!!

Press enter and as result open to.do.org file.
[image]

After file was open the AUTOMATE start REVERT BUFFER!!!
[image]

and as result the content of to.do.org file IS EMPTY!!!
[image]

How I can fix this?

P.S. If I work with any LOCAL org file then no problem. But with remote Google's drive file (org files) then has problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tramp supports Google drive out of the box. Try to open `C-x C-f /gdrive:your.name@gmail.com:/path/to/file`.

Starting with Tramp 2.4, it supports also rclone. If you have configured Google drive in rclone as, say, `my-google`, try `C-x C-f /rclone:my-google:/path/to/file`. Tramp 2.4 will be part of the upcoming Emacs 27.1. It is available already via GNU ELPA.

In both cases, your Google drive files might be integrated better into Emacs.

Comment: Has Emacs support Tramp mode for Dropbox?

Comment: In Tramp mode I can't delete remote file. I get error: file-error: Couldn’t delete /gdrive:alexei28@gmail.com:/Personal/TODO/original/to.do.org

Comment: Tramp has no dedicated support for Dropbox. However, rclone supports Dropbox, and so shall Tramp. I haven't tested myself.

Comment: In general, deleting files via Tramp's gdrive method works. So there might be a permission problem. If you want further analysis, pls contact me via the `tramp-devel@gnu.org` mailing list.

Comment: What do I have to do to enable the gdrive method? I'm running emacs built from git with tramp version 2.5.0-prenil and it says `[Method 'gdrive' is not known]`.

Comment: The gdrive method needs GVFS, which is installed on GNU/Linux machines usually. Furthermore, you must configure your Google drive account in the GNOME Online Accounts app. The Tramp manual shall mention this; if you feel it's not sufficient, pls tell me that I could precise it.